# Embedding IEEE articles into one PDF file with bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks, embedfile

Good morning, people.

My concern is probably simple enough to be replied fast by you, experienced people.
I want to embed several `IEEEtran` articles into one PDF file—this to embed the same article several times in different languages—, I want it to have bookmarks to navigate from one article to another one in another language. For instance:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{English}
\autor{doe}
\begin{document}
\section{1}
Thing.
\section{2}
More thing.
\subsection{Crap 3}
More thingy thing.
\end{document}
```

is one IEEE article in English,

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{Spanish}
\autor{Doe}
\begin{document}
\section{1}
Cosa.
\section{2}
Más cosa.
\subsection{Crap 3}
Más coseada cosa.
\end{document}
```

is the same article in Spanish and

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{Portuguese}
\autor{Doe}
\begin{document}
\section{1}
Coisa.
\section{2}
Mais coisa.
\subsection{Crap 3}
Mais cosiadinha coisa.
\end{document}
```

is the article in Portuguese.
I want these three totally independent files with their respective independent titles in a single PDF which will have bookmarks for section, subsection and else of each article in the main PDF. I was adviced to use `'\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{bookmark}` which I know how to use in a single file but not embedding several files into a “main” one. I want to learn how to do it to use it in my college articles and reports which I need to write in several languages. Thanks in advance everyone for your support. :)!

Comment: If you only want to link to the beginning of each language, you could include each article as a pdf using the `pdfpages` package and separately write the link into the overall document that includes all the articles...

Comment: @darthbith I do not get your point. Would you please give me a minimal example? I do not want to place links on a document, I want to use the bookmarks available in a column at one side of the PDF viewer such as Adobe Reader. The Adobe Reader bookmarks, not verbatim hyperlinks to the documents in the overall document. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) package (which automatically loads [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) and the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package. First, compile your three test documents so you have the three PDFs (I've modified them slightly). Then, use the final code to compile everything together. There are several disadvantages to this approach, including:

1. All internal links in the included PDFs will be lost (i.e. links to figures and references). You can get around this using the [`pax`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pax) package, but the process is a little more involved. Search around on this site for instructions on how to use `pax`
2. Pages will no longer be numbered consecutively

---

`english.tex`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{English}
\author{doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{1}
Thing.
\section{2}
More thing.
\subsection{Crap 3}
More thingy thing.
\end{document}
```

`spanish.tex`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Spanish}
\author{Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{1}
Cosa.
\section{2}
Más cosa.
\subsection{Crap 3}
Más coseada cosa.
\end{document}
```

`portugese.tex`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{Portuguese}
\author{Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{1}
Coisa.
\section{2}
Mais coisa.
\subsection{Crap 3}
Mais cosiadinha coisa.
\end{document}
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran} % Actually, you can probably use any document class, I picked this one so the margins should match
\pagestyle{empty} % Set pagestyle empty because the imported pdfs will have their own style
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark} % This package should be loaded after all other packages, except those listed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/32374

\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{English}{English}
\includepdf[pages=-]{english.pdf}

\pdfbookmark{Spanish}{Spanish}
\includepdf[pages=-]{spanish.pdf}

\pdfbookmark{Portugese}{Portugese}
\includepdf[pages=-]{portugese.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I can deal without the internal PDF links, I will try to figure out how to do it soon. Just like they were chapters of a book, these, composed of sections and subsections. Instead of chapters, they are just articles in different PDF files. Thank you for your support. I shall use this in next articles. :)