# Combining several pdf files into a single pdf file. How can I include all of the bookmarks?

Tags: pdfpages, bookmarks, combine

I have about ten pdf files, all of which have bookmarks. I want to combine all ten files into a single file. I also want all the bookmarks to be retained in the process.

Here is my current method to combine the files:

```
\documentclass{article}% or something else
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{file1}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file2}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file3}
\includepdf[pages=-]{file4}

\end{document}
```

[This previous question is similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220706/67392) to my question. [This one is also similar.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284632)

However, I don't want to create any new bookmarks, I just want to import them all.

Comment: It is theoretically possible: you can readd the destinations with the newpax package  and one could  also extract the bookmark info to recombine them. But I'm not aware of a concrete implementation in LaTeX.

Comment: If you only want to combine several PDFs, you can try using ghostscript to combine them. The bookmarks should be kept then.

Comment: @JasperHabicht You are right, this work very well.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, @Jasper Habict made the following suggestion:

> If you only want to combine several PDFs, you can try using ghostscript to combine them. The bookmarks should be kept then.

They are right about that. I installed ghostscript and [used the command I found here](https://gist.github.com/brenopolanski/2ae13095ed7e865b60f5):

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=combine.pdf -dBATCH 1.pdf 2.pdf
```

I needed to add `-dNOSAFER` as well to allow access to my file system.