# how to include a title frame that does not go with the theme?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, presentations, frame-title

I am working on a presentation on beamer and i used the theme Madrid but i am obliged to use the title page ppt template given by my institution, how do i have the first page as the template and the rest of the presentation following the theme ?
[image: screenshot of the ppt template]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide the title page template given by your institution.

Comment: Thank you!, i actually can't because it's a PPT file but i will provide a screenshot

Comment: Probably the easiest is to create the title slide in Powerpoint, export to pdf, create the full presentation in beamer without a title slide, and then combine the two pdf files afterwards.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691446/combining-several-pdf-files-into-a-single-pdf-file-how-can-i-include-all-of-the (only the answer, the question is not immediately related).

Comment: You can use `\setbeamertemplate{title page}{...}` to customize the title page. But the code for `...` is not quite easy.

Comment: Using a background image might help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame

Comment: thank you all for your help, if this could help anyone all the solutions were good but the one i went for is that i did my presentation in beamer got it in pdf and then converted it to ppt and added my title page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sketch of the solution using a backgroundimage:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Global Background must be put in preamble
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{%
    % to scale the image such that it fills the entire slide  
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{ARlys.png}%

    % alternative: scale the image such that the it fits best into the 
    % slide without changing the aspect ratio
    %\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{ARlys.png}%
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}%{First slide}
        This is the content of the first slide
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}%{Second slide}
        This is the content of the second slide
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You should adjust the background image to your own specs. With the given image this looks like this:

[image]

If you want to have the background image only for a specific frame,  you simply wrap the whole begin-end frame block in curly braces. In between `{` and `\begin{frame}` you can insert the `\usebackgroundtemplate{...}` command. This then acts only locally for the frame inside the curly braces.

This is should be enough to give you the idea ;)

Comment: Probably from the second slide onwards the background image is no longer needed.

Comment: That's an easy one: you simply wrap the whole begin-end frame block in curly braces. In between `{` and `\begin{frame}` you can insert the `\usebackgroundtemplate` command. This then acts only locally for the frame inside the curly braces. I've added this to my answer as well.

Comment: +1, with one minor suggestion: I would add `keepaspectratio` to avoid distorting the header.

Comment: you're right, `keepaspectratio` can be useful but usually I'd rather risk a little bit of difference in scaling along x and y direction than leaving a white margin somewhere. In any case, good idea -- I'll write a short comment on that.